# Windows Batch For Loop How?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have below code and I like to repeat the process based on INPUT Y at the line:

REM If value below is Y, repeat the process
   SET /P repeat=do you want to do the same for other systems ?:

How do I do that by using LOOP?

```
@ECHO OFF
:: List of Systems as Vairable
set "SB1=hannlsb1.mydomain.com:30515 -i 05"
set "DB1=hannlsd2.mydomain.com:31315    -i 13"
set "QB1=hannlsqa1-1:30115 -i 01"
set "DB0=hannlsd1.mydomain.com  -i 10"
set "QB0=hannlsps1-1.mydomain.com-i 03"
set "WB1=hannlsqa1-1:30315 -i 03"
set "VB1=hannlsvt-1.mydomain.com    -i 01"

SET /P isid=Please enter isid:
SET /P pass=Please enter password to be reset:

REM NEED LOOP Here
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /P sysid=Please enter SystemID:
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%i IN (`echo+!%sysid%!`) DO SET val=%%i
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

IF NOT "%val%"=="" (
   REM ECHO Hello %sysid%, Welcome to DOS inputs!
   ECHO %val%
   REM If value below is Y, repeat the process
   SET /P repeat=do you want to do the same for other systems ?:
) ELSE (
   ECHO You did not enter Correct System ID! Bye bye!!
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a FOR. Just an IF

Create a separate subroutine.Bat file with params and code that does your task.

Then call that subroutine command within the subroutine.  Recursively.

Or if you want to use a for loop and get them to enter all the sysid's in a comma separated list the first time: Use a For loop to call the subroutine.bat with the sysid as one of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

no loop needed. Just a "if ... goto ...". I recommend `choice`, as it has it's own errorhandling (no need to mess with wrong or weird user input):

```
:loop
REM do your stuff
choice /c YN /M "Want to repeat?"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :loop
```

see `goto /?` and `choice /?` for more information.